# gulp watch TypeError: glob pattern string required

Tags: gulp, poedit, po

I've .po files in my application. I've created a watch to see when the translations file have been changed and compile them

```
gulp.task('translations', () => gulp
  .src('po/.*po',) 
  .pipe(gettext.compile({format: 'json'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/translations/')));
)

gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch('po/**/*.po', ['translations']);
});
```

I use [poedit](https://poedit.net/) if I do some change it works, but if I just click save button without a new change the gulp process die throwing the error `TypeError: glob pattern string required`

### Update

I've changed gulp.watch for gulp-watch package and it throws me better info

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/rkmax/Development/MyProject/po/es_ES.temp.po'
```

Comment: A full stack trace would be helpful, but it sounds like a bug with either gulp watch or poedit.

Comment: @helion3 I've updated the question with more info. there's some way I can ignore that temp.go files

Comment: @rkmax: You can negate/ignore files with the `!` character in your globs. So try, using `['po/**/*.po', '!po/**/*.temp.po']`

Comment: No luck. still throwing the same error